# Rails simple_form add class to collection input based on collection item attribute

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, collections, simple-form

I would like to add a css class to the input element of only some of the collection boxes based on the collection items attribute.

Here is my collection.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :group_ids, @groups, :id, :name, :checked => @user.group_ids %>
```

To add a class to all of the inputs, I could do

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :group_ids, @groups, :id, :name, :checked => @user.group_ids, input_html: { class: 'getsClass' } %>
```

But I only need it on some of the inputs, I need something along the lines of

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :group_ids, @groups, :id, :name, :checked => @user.group_ids, input_html: { class: {group.new == true ? "getsClass"} } %>
```

but I can not access the group.  Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: The best thing I could find to an answer to your question on how to do this was here:  http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-change-class-of-a-label-for-checkboxes-in-simple_form/#answer-15036409

Comment: Same problem. Did you find an answer ?